# Http запросы сайта

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток! как можно получить все http запросы сайта? 
т.е. запросы вида GET<что-нибудь> 
В общем, если еще конкретнее - то при загрузке сайта кроме запроса Get относящемуся к самому сайту, обрабатываются запросы на загрузку картинок и т.п. Как можно получить эти запросы?

Comment: это очень нечеткий вопрос

Comment: исправил вопрос

Comment: оборжаться просто. форуму петросяна очень не хватает таких искрометных личночтей

Comment: уважаемый человек на ответах mail.ru

Comment: Петросяны- идите на ответы.мэйл.ру,
где уже нормальные вопросы по regexp, javascript, html, php, java, python ?

Answer (score 1):

На стороне клиента (браузера) или сервера?

Если из браузера - то можно с помощью встроенных менеджеров (обычно открываются правым кликом по странице - "Проинспектировать элемент" - Network). Перезагружаете страницу, и в диаграме будут указаны все запросы, и их время. Так же можно воспользоваться программой HTTP Analyzer V6, она очень подробно расписывает весь трафик.

Если же на сервере - то поучите устройство TCP/IP. Каждый запрос происходит в новой сессии подключения, напрямую из скрипта php это ни как не получить. Если же нужно только для информации - можно каждый запрос сохранять в файл. Либо настроить логирование в apache или другом вэб-сервере.

PS: По поводу "петросянства" - каков вопрос (первый вариант), таков и ответ.

Comment: на стороне сервера. Я хочу сделать анализ запросов, примерно, как здесь http://www.pr-cy.ru/a/3dnews.ru#analysis-content

Comment: Тогда нужно придумывать систему логирования в базу. Как это сделать для apache я не знаю, для nginx где-то видел подобный скрипт. На стороне php этого не сделать. PS: для своего сайта, или для чужих?

Comment: для чужих сайтов